# Symbol Motorola mc65 and datawedge

Tags: symbols, motorola

i have an windows mobile application written in c# compact framework which use barcode scanner. In fact that i need to keep my app device independent i don't use constructor's api but i handle scanner through events like form_keypress using an preamble.

It is a really good way for any device until i tried to install in motorola mc65 with windows 6.5.3 which is configured to switch off datawedge utility after some time of idling. The weird is that in other motorola devices like mc55 or es400 there is no problem and datawedge stay on untill user sett it off from settings menu.

Is there any way to force motorola mc65 to keep datawedge on without usage of it's api in my application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two options to keep the Datawedge active without going idle or being "Stopped".

1. Navigate to the datawedge application on the scanner and under Advance Configuration and then Settings, make sure "Autostart" is enabled.
2. You can add a file to the scanner's system via Windows Mobile Device Center that will make sure datawedge is always active.  Open Notepad and paste the following in:

> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Motorola\DWStartUp]
>   "DontLoadOnStartUp"=dword:00000000

Save the file as: datawedge.reg.txt

- Copy and paste the file from your computer into Application folder on the scanner via Windows Mobile Device Center.
- Navigate to the temp directory on the scanner.
- Tap on the datawedge icon.
- Merge it from device (click Yes), then cold boot (hold 1, 9 and Power for 3 seconds)

Comment: Good answer ;)! is there any way to do this without rebooting? Thanks!