# Datawedge scanner in Motorola MC92N0 goes idle on some pages in Internet Explorer

Tags: windows-mobile, barcode-scanner, windows-embedded-compact, windows-embedded, datawedge

I have a problem with barcode scanner on Motorola MC92N0 device running on Windows Embedded Compact 6.5.

Sometimes when I open some page in Internet Explorer scanner stops working and in Datawedge application it shows status IDLE. Behaviour is very strange because when I switch between different pages in IE, scanner activates on some pages but deactivates on others. I tried to disable scripts in IE, but this does not changed anything, so this is not a matter of JavaScript on some pages.

I tried solution from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9210209/symbol-motorola-mc65-and-datawedge) to prevent scanner from going idle but it doesn't help. I have autostart in Datawedge checked and scanner goes idle anyway.

Is this some kind of bug in Internet Explorer or Datawedge? Do you know if there are some logs from datawedge that shows why scanner deactivates?

Comment: does the datawedge show additional info below IDLE (ie Capture device not available). There seems to be an advanced option Capturemode:only to empty input field. The wedge will be only enabled when the focus is on an empty input field. Post your setup and the web pages that show with Datawedge=Idle

Comment: There is "Capture device not available" text below IDLE status when it is not working. Capture mode is set to always.

Comment: I do not know all possible Zebra Datawedge Settings, but I assume there is one that makes the DateWedge going Idle for some of the Web pages. It would be good to see screen shots of the Web pages that 'work' and those that do not and of the datawedge settings (you may try to post a the Exported DataWedge settings). See also http://techdocs.zebra.com/datawedge/6-5/guide/about/

Answer (score 0):

Very likely this is a power management issue see paragraph **Drivers Power States** in http://nicolasbesson.blogspot.com/2008/04/power-management-under-window-ce-part.html  Possibly to the driver of the barcode scanner is attached an ActivityTimer or another power management component that disables the driver if you surf in the net too long or if wifi is active (on some webpages there is a constant data flow over wifi (webpages with many ads and trackers), on other not).

Power safe features like disabling peripherals like barcode scanners by letting the, sleep when other activites like internet surfing are performed is a common power safe feature (https://support.honeywellaidc.com/s/article/How-to-set-the-WLAN-Radio-WiFi-always-on-via-Intermec-Settings)